# Server 20.04.1 LTS "0 updates can be installed immediately, 0 of these updates are security updates"

Tags: server, updates, login

I have two servers running "vanilla" 20.04.1 LTS.  The only configuration changes relate to defining mount points, NFS shares, and Samba shares.  Each machine has a daily backup batch job invoked manually, after which, if there are no NFS or Samba connections, shut down.

I log on as root (save the lectures!) every morning and get system information, along with some promos and links.  The update count displayed is always zero on both machines.  However, if I invoke updates manually about once a week, updates happen, so the number displayed should not be zero.

I do not want automatic updates because I do not want arbitrary reboots in the middle of backup jobs on the LAN.  I am no fan of having anything happen automatically from outside control anyhow.

Therefore, I am asking how to get the correct number and type (security or not) of updates when I log on after boot.

Comment: The machines in question are up for about 30 minutes per day just to get their jobs duone, so scheduling updates for off-hours is impractical.

Comment: Unattended Upgrades won't reboot unless you enable the setting (do-not-reboot is the default setting). The same settings file lets you choose a reboot time specifically to avoid reboots in the middle of something else.

Comment: You cannot trust the login (motd) count of updates. That is created once daily at a random time...it might have been made yesterday...or the day before. The only accurate check is to run an apt-update after you login.

Comment: Question: Do you have the apt-daily and apt-daily-upgrade systemd timers enabled (`systemctl list-timers`)?

Comment: Yes, the apt-daily and apt-daily-upgrade timers are enabled.  Given all the comments (thanks!), I think it best for me to run an update cron job.

Answer (score 1):

**How to edit the existing systemd timer to run `apt update` at the time of your choosing**:

Edit `/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer`. Simply change these two lines:

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 6,18:00  <---- Change this to the time(s) that you want
RandomizedDelaySec=12h    <---- Comment out this line
Persistent=true
```

After editing, reload the timer:

`$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

**NOTE for future readers**: Unless you really need apt to run at a specific time, best practice is to leave the randomization in place to avoid hammering the Ubuntu servers with load at common times (that's rude). Thoughtful community members can use the `RandomizedDelaySec` setting to configure a window to spread that load and avoid hammering.

---

**How to disable Unattended Upgrades**:

Edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`.

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";           <--- apt update. leave it "1"
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";  <--- apt upgrade. Change to "0"
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "1";              <--- Unattended Upgrade feature. Change to "0"
```

**NOTE for future readers**: Disabling Unattended Upgrades is not recommended for most users. UU is how most users receive security patches. The Ubuntu developers expect users to run UU, do not test systems without UU, and are likely to reject bugs that cannot be duplicated with UU running. Disabling UU is hiking into the wilderness on your own. This case is presented specifically because the OP is willing to be responsible.

---

**How to discern between security and non-security upgrades**: For most users, this is an exercise in curiosity only. Most users should be getting daily security upgrades via Unattended Upgrades, and the number of upgrades is not particularly useful information. The OP asked specifically for this information.

The login message summarizing upgrades available generally cannot be trusted to be accurate -- that message is generated by pam_login, and is based upon the most recent  apt-update...which might have been days ago in this case. Always-on systems usually update apt twice daily, so their variance will usually be small.

Here's one fairly easy, method to list the -security packages available for upgrade. You can get other repos the same way, by editing the first command:

Reminder: Run a fresh `apt update` before this to ensure that you have an accurate list.

```
$ grep security /etc/apt/sources.list > /tmp/security.list
$ apt list --upgradeable -oDir::Etc::Sourcelist=/tmp/security.list
```